# How to define an explicit constructor for an url object in Java

Tags: java, constructor, processing

I am defining a url in processing (or java) with the line:

```
URL base = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
```

So I get the following error: *Default constructor cannot handle exception type MalformedURLException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor*. Which I assume is because if my url isn't valid, there's no corresponding `catch` to catch the error (because I'm declaring my url outside of `try`).

But, i want to define this url outside of `try`, because my main `try` block is in a loop and the url is static. So there's no need to do the definition of the url more than once (and because it's static i'm not afraid of any MalformedURLExceptions).

How do I do that? Is there really no other way than to define the url within a separate `try` block? (because that seems a bit too much for just a simple static url)

---

```
// import libraries
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

// url
URL base = new URL("http://www.google.com");

void setup() {
}

void draw() {
  try {
    // retrieve url
    String[] results = loadStrings(base);

    // print results
    println(results[0]);
  }  
  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (ConnectException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // stop looping
  noLoop();

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to define a default constructor for your class which throws MalformedURLException:

```
class MyClass {
    private URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

    public MyClass() throws MalformedURLException {}
}
```

The error is happening because the constructor Java is generating for your class isn't able to throw anything, you must specify that it might.

**Edit**

Seeing your code, your other option is this (I assume setup() gets called before you use the URL)

```
URL url;

void setup() {
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this isn't a class that i've written myself, just a standard [java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). Should i still define the default constructor like you suggested in that case? Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Then we need to see more code for where this error is happening. Can you post the code around where you're using this url?

Comment: Of course, added my code at the bottom of my question (this is processing code btw., might be a little different from standard java).

Comment: Whatever class your code that you posted is in needs a default constructor defined to throw `MalformedURLException`. I don't know processing that well, but I assume it's creating some type of implicit class for your code. This code needs some sort of constructor that can throw the error for the implicitly created URL.

Comment: So your class would do that right? When i use it i get the error "The field panel.url is not visible", and changing the url from private to public doesn't change the error.

Comment: You'd need to put all your code in the class, otherwise they don't have access to the URL.

Comment: The code in your edit worked (without having to write a whole new class). Btw. setup is a native function in processing that gets called once before the draw loop, so that's very applicable to me wanting to define the url only once. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good habit to just swallow the exception, even if you think it's never going to happen... Just wrap it in a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @Jordão Good plan, added for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `URL` constructor throws a checked exception **you have to either catch it or rethrow it**. You can create your own factory method that just wraps it in a `RuntimeException`:

```
public class URLFactory {
  public static URL create(String urlString) {
    try {
      return new URL(urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Or maybe just this in your environment?

```
URL createURL(String urlString) {
  try {
    return new URL(urlString);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

And use it instead:

```
URL base = URLFactory.create("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Ok. Could you elaborate a little? How do i do that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i added your runtimeexception to the code.